# What is the difference between "Auto focus" and "Macro" modes of focus?

Tags: settings, camera, focus

In Samsung Android phones, I've seen two options for selecting the focus mode which are Auto focus and Macro modes in the Camera settings. So, just want to know what is the difference between them? How it affects the output/result of image captured?

Answer (score 1):

- In general , [macro photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_photography#See_also) from wiki says

> ....is extreme close-up photography, usually of very small subjects, in which the size of the subject in the photograph is greater than life size...The ratio of the subject size on the film plane (or sensor plane) to the actual subject size is known as the reproduction ratio. Likewise, a macro lens is classically a lens capable of reproduction ratios of at least 1:1....

- From sister stack exchange {photography site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/24079)

> Life-size is the typical aim of "full macro" shots, which is to say you are working at a 1:1 reproduction ratio, shooting very small objects at close range. Insects, flower stamens, etc.

- *Auto Focus* by contrast is letting the camera decide the best settings eliminating user intervention - see 
  [How Does Autofocus Actually Work?](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/autofocus-actually-work/)

While these definitions should be applicable to Android as such, the quality would obviously depend on bunch of things like *lens, zoom,megapixel and pre /post photo processing built in*